# what is the interval of integration of $\int^a_b \frac {dx}{dt}dt $

Tags: integration

for $\int^a_b dt$ the interval of integration is [a,b] so how about
$$\int^a_b \frac {dx}{dt}dt = \int^a_b dx $$
Does the interval of integral still [a,b] or it's changed. If it's, in what way it's changed?

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be multiple issues:

1. If $a < b$, then $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} \dots$ denotes an integral over $[a, b]$. (The left-hand endpoint is the *lower* limit.)
2. If $b < a$, then $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} \dots = -\int_{b}^{a} \dots$, and the interval of integration would be $[b, a]$.
3. If $x$ is a continuously-differentiable function on $[a, b]$, the "substitution rule" or "change of variables formula" reads
   $$
   \int_{a}^{b} \frac{dx}{dt}\, dt = \int_{x(a)}^{x(b)} dx.
   $$
   (By the fundamental theorem, each side is equal to $x(b) - x(a)$.) Thus, the interval of integration on the right is $\bigl[x(a), x(b)\bigr]$ if $x(a) < x(b)$, or is $\bigl[x(b), x(a)\bigr]$ if $x(b) < x(a)$.

Comment: Hi, if there's extra element like $e^{-st}\frac{dx}{dt}$ then the interval is still [x(b),x(a)], right?

Comment: If you invoke the change of variables theorem as in 3., then yes (though you're no longer integrating $e^{-st}$, but its compositon with $x$). One reason I gave contingencies is I'm not entirely sure what you're "really asking"; I sense there's an underlying, unstated motivation for your question. Part of this suspicion comes from your usage of Leibniz notation in a general setting, with $x$ denoting both a function on the left and a dummy variable of integration on the right. This is risky, particularly for your specific question. :)

Comment: Well, I am learning Laplace transformation and it's the transformation of the derivative of a function. That is for example $f(t)=\frac{d(g(t))}{dt}$ then you have the Laplace transformation

Comment: As you know, the Laplace transform of a function $f$ is$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}f(t)\, dt.$$ If $f = g'$ is everywhere positive or everywhere negative, if $G$ is an antiderivative with inverse $G^{-1}$, and if you substitute $x = G(t)$, so that $dx = G'(t)\, dt = f(t)\, dt$, then$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}f(t)\, dt = \int_{G(0)}^{G(\infty)} e^{-sG^{-1}(x)}\, dx.$$If $f$ changes sign, however, then $G$ has no global inverse, and the preceding requires modification. I'm guessing this isn't what you had in mind...?

Comment: Yes, I don't think it'll get that complicated. So basically, the Leibniz notation can be use carelessly inside integral, means that normal multiplication or division cannot applied to them

Answer (score 1):

Using the Change of Variables Theorem:

> Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function and $g:[c,d]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with continuous derivative and $g([c,d])\subseteq [a,b]$. Then
>   \begin{equation}
> \int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}f(x)\,dx=\int_c^d f(g(t))g'(t)\,dt.
> \end{equation}
>   We say that the variable $x$ changed to $g(t)$.

In your case, we clearly have $f(x) = 1$. So you must know the function $g(t)$ to compute $\frac{dx}{dt}$, which is$\frac{dg(t)}{dt}$. Thus, if $g$ is a bijection,
\begin{equation}
\int_b^a\,dx=\int_{g^{-1}(b)}^{g^{-1}(a)}\frac{dx}{dt}\,dt.
\end{equation}
So, for example, if you defined $x=t$, then $g(t) = t$ and $\frac{dx}{dt} = 1$. Therefore
\begin{equation}
\int_{g^{-1}(b)}^{g^{-1}(a)}\frac{dx}{dt}\,dt= \int_b^a \,dt
\end{equation}
and your interval would not change. For other functions $g$, your interval may change.

Comment: But $g^{-1}(a) = \frac{c}{a}$...

Comment: Fixed. $\frac{a}{c}$, actually. But, my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

The differentials $dt$ cancel out. So you are referring to variable $x$ only and its interval is $(a,b)$ and its integral is $(a-b)$.